# How to write function for optional parameters in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, plpgsql

My requirement is write optional parameters to a function. Parameters are optional sometimes I will add or I will not pass parameters to function. Can anyone help me how to write function?

I am writing like:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM test 
WHERE field3 IN ('value1','value2') 
AND ($1 IS null OR field1 = $1) 
AND ($2 IS null OR field2 = $2) 
AND ($3 IS null OR field3 = $3);
```

I am passing parameters to Query but my output is not expected.when I pass all three parameters my output is correct,otherwise it is not expected output.

Comment: I want to use and,or conditions in my function.

Answer (score 159, accepted):

You can define optional parameters by supplying a default value.

```
create function foo(p_one integer default null, 
                    p_two integer default 42, 
                    p_three varchar default 'foo')
  returns text
as
$$
begin
    return format('p_one=%s, p_two=%s, p_three=%s', p_one, p_two, p_three);
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

You can "leave out" parameters from the end, so `foo()`, `foo(1)` or `foo(1,2)` are valid. If you want to only supply a parameter that is not the first you have to use the syntax that specifies the parameter names.

```
select foo();
```

returns: `p_one=, p_two=42, p_three=foo`

```
select foo(1);
```

returns: `p_one=1, p_two=42, p_three=foo`

```
select foo(p_three => 'bar')
```

returns: `p_one=, p_two=42, p_three=bar`

Comment: can i use select Statement instead of return format in above function?.If i use select statement i am getting error like "query has no destination for result data"

Comment: @indu: that is a totally different question which is answered in the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW

Answer (score 6):

Apart of the [VARIADIC](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-VARIADIC-FUNCTIONS) option pointed by @a_horse_with_no_name, which is only a syntax sugar for passing an array with any number of elements **of the same type**, you *can't* define a function with optional parameters because, in postgres, functions are identified not only by its name but also by its arguments and the types of them.

That is: `create function foo (int) [...]` and `create function foo (varchar) [...]` will create **different** functions.

Which is called when you execute, for example, `select foo(bar)` depends on *bar* data type itself. That is: if it is an integer, you will call the first one and if it is varchar, then second one will be called.

More than that: if you execute, for example, `select foo(now())`, then a *function not exists* exception will be triggered.

So, as I said, you can't implement functions with variable arguments, **but you can implement multiple functions with the same name and distinct argument (an/or type) sets returning the same data type**.

If you (obviously) doesn't want to implement the function twice, the only thing you need to do is to implement a "master" function with all possible parameters and the others (which have fewer parameters) only calling the "master" one with default values for the non received parameters.

Answer (score 0):

As an option, I got a function i tested with Navicat App:
`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "public"."for_loop_through_query"(sponsor_name varchar default 'Save the Children')`
It generates me this. (Note: Please look at the parameter difference)
`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "public"."for_loop_through_query"("sponsor_name" varchar='Save the Children'::character varying)`

```sql
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "public"."for_loop_through_query"("sponsor_name" varchar='Save the Children'::character varying)
  RETURNS "pg_catalog"."void" AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    rec RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN SELECT
      companies."name" AS org_name,
      "sponsors"."name" AS sponsor_name
      FROM
      "donor_companies"
      JOIN "sponsors"
      ON "donor_companies"."donor_id" = "sponsors"."id" 
      JOIN companies
      ON "donor_companies"."organization_id" = companies."id"
      WHERE
      "public"."sponsors"."name" = sponsor_name
    LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE '%', rec.org_name;
  END LOOP;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a default value to `IN`, `INOUT` and `VARIADIC` parameters as shown below. *The parameter with or without `IN` is an `IN` parameter:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func(
  IN num1 INTEGER DEFAULT 1, 
  INOUT num2 INTEGER DEFAULT 2,
  VARIADIC nums INTEGER[] DEFAULT ARRAY[3,4]
)
AS $$
BEGIN
  SELECT num1 + num2 + nums[1] + nums[2] INTO num2;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Or:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func(
  IN INTEGER DEFAULT 1,
  INOUT INTEGER DEFAULT 2,
  VARIADIC INTEGER[] DEFAULT ARRAY[3,4]
)
AS $$
BEGIN
  SELECT $1 + $2 + $3[1] + $4[2] INTO $2;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then, calling `my_func()` returns `5` as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT my_func();
 my_func
---------
      10
(1 row)
```

Be careful, setting a default value to an `OUT` parameter gets the error below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func(OUT num INTEGER DEFAULT 2)
AS $$                -- ↑↑↑             ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑
BEGIN
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

> ERROR:  only input parameters can have default values